# Discrete group of isometries of a finitely compact metric space is countable.

Tags: general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

This question comes from Ratcliffe's *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds*.

> Let $X$ be a finitely compact metric space (i.e. all closed metric balls are compact). Prove that a discrete group $\Gamma$ of isometries of a $X$ is countable.

$X$ being finitely compact tells us that $\Gamma$ also acts discontinuously on $X$ (this is a theorem in the text). Apparently it also tells us that $X$ is second-countable (the author just says this; I've not seen it proven, but I'm willing to accept is as fact for now). My thought is to somehow appeal to this discontinuous action on the closed, compact metric balls $\bar{B_i}$, where $\{B_i\}$ is the countable base for the topology. However, I've not successfully figured out a way to mix these two ideas.

Does anyone have any suggestions for other approaches?

If it matters, this isn't a homework question - I'm studying for my comprehensive exams next month and I thought this seemed like a reasonable practice exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a base point $p$. For each integer valued radius $n$, ask yourself: how many $\gamma \in \Gamma$ are there such that $d(p,\gamma \cdot p) \le n$? Can you see how to use compactness of $B(p,n)$ to prove this number is finite? Can you then finish the proof?

Comment: I think I see the finiteness of $\Gamma p \cap B(p,n)$ (since the orbit is discrete), but I'm not totally sure how it finishes the proof. Are you suggesting somehow that we can get a base for the topology using open balls of various radii centered at the points in the orbit $\Gamma p$?

Comment: Consider the union $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left( \Gamma \cap B(p,n) \right)$$

Comment: Oh ok, that makes it perfectly clear now. Thanks!

Comment: It is my pleasure.